# Function to send e-mail with attachment and body

Tags: bash, sendmail

I have the e-mail body set in $email_template as per the e.g. below and then want to use the function to send an e-mail with an attachment e.g. `do_mail attachment.csv user@domain.com`.

```
$email_template="Subject: Listing - `date --date="tomorrow" +"%A %d %B %Y"`
From: no-reply@domain.com
To: $2
Content-Type: plain/text

Please see attached listing - `date --date="tomorrow" +"%A %d %B %Y"`
"

do_mail () {
        uuencode $1 $1 | 
        printf "$email_template" "$2" | 
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
}
```

Is there some error in this as there is no e-mail sent?

Comment: If you are unclear about that, print your `$email_template` and/or replace the `sendmail` call with a mere `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the `$2` substitution you wanted to do is not finished. It can't be used on defining the string, and you use `printf` to set it in, so you should have a `%s` in the template.

Secondly, the pipe is weird. I think, you rather mean

```
do_mail () {
    {
        printf "$email_template" "$2"
        uuencode "$1" "$1"
    } | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
}
```